# How do I prevent connections in ZeroMQ?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a PUSH/PULL set up, but there is nothing stopping someone who know the IP address and port where the PULL socket is binding and sending garbage to it. What is the correct way to prevent this and only allow client I have authorized to connect to it?

If this isn't possible can I just tell the socket to only accept one (the first) connection and ignore any subsequent ones?

Comment: I think I found a solution: https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/examples/security/strawhouse.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using ZeroMQ >= 4.0? If so then you can take advantage of the new security features. Pieter Hintjens gives the overview on his blog: http://hintjens.com/blog:48

The PLAIN authentication method allows simple username / password authentication. See the documentation here: http://api.zeromq.org/4-1:zmq-plain

Comment: Yeah I'm using the latest version thanks seems like a good solution.